# Email Process to send email on every other thursday(biweekly)

Tags: outsystems

I am having little confusion as how to set the timer on the email that is sent now to just only on every other thursday.
[image]
I am new to Outsystems and not sure how can I proceeed with this. Can anyone please help me, is there any samples available now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ServiceCenter/eSpace_Timer_Edit you have the options to configure the timers daily, weekly, Day of month, weekday of month or when publish

Answer (score 2):

Just click on Timer. In properties window of timers, you will find "schedule" property. Double click on that property and decide when you want to run.

If you want to run timer on alternate Thursday, inside timer action, before sending e-mail you need to check what is current day. If it is alternate Thursday, sent an e-mail else don't.

Hope this helps.

Suraj Borade